# How to force execution of a main loop at exact time intervals?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, .net-core, azure-iot-edge

This is the simplified scheme of the IoT Edge Modbus module: https://github.com/Azure/iot-edge-modbus
The application polls some data from Modbus-TCP devices. It creates individual tasks for reading registers. Reading is performed at specified time intervals.
When number of tasks > 500, "While" loop in the "Start" method, begins to hang. The code inside the While loop isn't excuted at PublishInterval.
The more SingleOperation tasks application has, the less often "While-loop" code is executed.

How can I modify this code to be shure that the code in the While loop executes exactly on time (after PublishInterval)?

```
static List<Task> m_task_list = new List<Task>();
static bool m_run = true;
static int PublishInterval = 1800000;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Init().Wait();
}

static async Task Init()
{
    m_task_list.Add(Start(userContext));
}


static async Task Start(object userContext)
{
    //Creating of 5000+ tasks that poll data (read 1-2 registers) from Modbus-TCP devices. Each task works 24/7 and polls data after some interval (for example: 15min)  
    foreach (var op in Operations)
    {
        Task t = Task.Run(async () => await SingleOperation(op.Params));
        m_taskList.Add(t);
    }

    while (m_run)
    {
        //Compose the read data into Amqp messages and send them to IoT Hub
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} I am alive!");
    
        if (!m_run)
        {
            break;
        }
        await Task.Delay(PublishInterval);      
    }
}
```

Comment: Initial comments deleted ... I think there is a basic misunderstanding here, how Task/async works.

Comment: Does adding the line `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100);` at the start of the program makes any difference? Btw I am not endorsing to add permanently this configuration. It's just to help identify the problem.

Comment: It this not simply due to CPU contention? I.e. you have many more threads running that CPU cores, so your loop gets starved. Either get more cores, or throttle the number of concurrent tasks you are scheduling.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, thank you. After adding ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(300, 300) my problem disappeared.

Comment: Browen this indicates that your asynchronous methods include synchronous/blocking calls. Is there any `Thread.Sleep()` lurking somewhere? If I was in your place I would investigate the issue, because having so many threads blocked could affect scalability.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, The module has "await Task.Delay" in the SingleOperation method. To make a pause (15minutes) between registers polling.

Also "Task.Delay" exists in ReadResponse method, to make a pause (50ms) between each retry attempt (max 10), and check socket.Available property. If "Available" then execute socket.Receive.
Also module uses class SemaphoreSlim in the SendRequest method where m_socket.Send and ReadResponse surrounded with m_semaphore_connection.Wait() and m_semaphore_connection.Release().

Comment: This module developed by Microsoft. Available in AzureMarketplace https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/microsoft_iot.edge-modbus?tab=overview
I thought it must be written without "child" errors.

Comment: The `SemaphoreSlim` has a `WaitAsync` method that can be awaited. You could try replacing the `Wait` with `WaitAsync` if possible.

Comment: Setting ThreadPool.SetMinThreads helped for Linux, but not for Windows.
After switching from Wait to WaitAsync for SemaphoreSlim, the problem has gone for Windows too.